# How to compare columns values with sum function in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have three tables :

1. mls_category
2. points_martix
3. mls_entry

My first table (mls_category) is like below:

```
*--------------------------------*
| cat_no |  store_id | cat_value |
*--------------------------------*
|   10   |    101    |     1     |
|   11   |    101    |     4     |
*--------------------------------*
```

My second table (points_martix) is like below:

```
*----------------------------------------------------*
| pm_no |  store_id | value_per_point | max_distance |
*----------------------------------------------------*
|   1   |    101    |       1         |      10      |
|   2   |    101    |       2         |      50      |
|   3   |    101    |       3         |      80      |
*----------------------------------------------------*
```

My third table (mls_entry) is like below:

```
*-------------------------------------------*
| user_id |  category | distance |  status  |
*-------------------------------------------*
|    1    |     10    |    20    | approved |
|    1    |     10    |    30    | approved |
|    1    |     11    |    40    | approved |
*-------------------------------------------*
```

I am using the following query to show the sum of  distance with some condition:

```
SELECT SUM(t1.totald/c.cat_value)
AS total_distance 
FROM mls_category c 
JOIN 
    (SELECT SUM(distance) totald, user_id, category 
     FROM mls_entry 
     WHERE user_id = 1
     AND status = 'approved' 
     GROUP BY user_id, category) t1 
ON c.cat_no = t1.category
```

This gives me sum **60** as total_distance, that is correct which I wanted.

Now, I want to include the third table (points_matrix) and want to compare my `sum(60)` is less than or equal to 80(max_distance) then my new value would be `60*3=180`.

So, suppose my sum comes **10** then my new value will be `10*1=10` and if my sum comes **25** then my new value will be according to point matrix `25*2=50`.

Comment: Does a higher max distance always equate to a higher value per point? If so, just join on all the matrix rows where the max distance is greater than or equal to your total, then choose the min() of your calculation...

Comment: @MatBailie No,  I am trying to calculate the sum of the distance  according to point_matrix, Means if my sum comes 9 then my new sum will 9*1 = 9 and if my sum 11 then new sum will 11*2 = 22.

Comment: Yes, `MIN(total_distance * value_per_point)` *(the min of your calculation)* for records where `the max distance is greater than or equal to your total` would do it... As per the answer that you accepted, though without confirming whether `a higher max distance always equate to a higher value per point`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yon can using `MIN()` to calculate what `value_per_point` you need, and the whole sql is like this:

```
SELECT MIN(b.value_per_point) * d.total_distance FROM points_matrix b 
JOIN 
(
    SELECT store_id, sum(t1.totald/c.cat_value) as total_distance FROM mls_category c 
    JOIN 
    (
        SELECT SUM(distance) totald, user_id, category FROM mls_entry 
        WHERE user_id= 1 AND status = 'approved' GROUP BY user_id, category
    ) t1 ON c.cat_no = t1.category
) d ON b.store_id = d.store_id AND b.max_distance >= d.total_distance
```

Comment: Makes the unstated assumption that I questioned in my comment to the OP : Only works if the `value_per_point` ***always*** increases as the `max_distance` increases.  *(If there was a row for max_distance = 9999 with value_per_point = 0, this would always return a score of 0.)*

Comment: @MatBailie Yes, the answer is established for this question, for your extension of question, it need to analyze what it depends.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Correlated Subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/correlated-subqueries.html):

```
SELECT 
  dt.total_distance * dt.max_points 
FROM (
      SELECT SUM(t1.totald/c.cat_value) AS total_distance, 
             (
              SELECT value_per_point 
              FROM points_martix 
              WHERE SUM(t1.totald/c.cat_value) >= max_distance
              ORDER BY max_distance ASC LIMIT 1
             ) AS max_points 
      FROM mls_category AS c 
      JOIN (
            SELECT SUM(distance) AS totald, 
                   user_id, 
                   category 
            FROM mls_entry 
            WHERE user_id= 1 AND 
                  status = 'approved' 
            GROUP BY user_id, category
           ) AS t1 on c.cat_no = t1.category
    ) AS dt
```

Comment: I have tried but the answer is coming wrong.. this gives me 150 but the answer should be 180 because of the sum is 60 and as per point matrix it is less then 80 then the value per point is 3 so answer will be 60*3 = 180.

Comment: @SantoshKhatri can you provide a DB fiddle or SQL fiddle ?